# Using Youtube Javascript API for multiple videos

Tags: api, youtube

I am trying to find a way to use Youtube API to have multiple videos with each in its own hidden div where each one is called up by their corresponding thumbnails. I am having a hard time finding out how to get the close button of the once hidden div to also stop that particular video. I can only get one to do it right and the other will not. My code below:

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {    
  player1 = new YT.Player('popupVid1', {
    height: '408',
    width: '725',
    videoId: '6Bp1c3-AeXQ',
    playerVars: {
      wmode: "opaque"
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });

  player2 = new YT.Player('popupVid2', {
    height: '408',
    width: '725',
    videoId: '6Bp1c3-AeXQ',
    playerVars: {
      wmode: "opaque"
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}


// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    setTimeout(stopVideo,loop);
    done = true;
  }
}

function stopVideo1() {
  player1.stopVideo();
}

function stopVideo2() {
  player2.stopVideo();
}
```

Comment: I edited the above code towards the end where I have the stopVideo1 and stopVideo2 functions. I identified the players and now the above script works for Firefox and Chrome but does not work for IE. Go figure that I have to have the bad boy be a scrooge. Do not know what to do from here for IE.

Comment: Let me add that the above does work in IE but not the stop feature that i edited above: function stopVideo1() {
player1.stopVideo();
}
function stopVideo2() {
player2.stopVideo();
}

Comment: Well, the strangest thing happened. I was solving another problem where I had lightbox divs poping up underneath the video and not over it. I did my research and added [wmode: "opaque"] to the script and that not only solved my problem with overlapping issues but now IE will stop the video when you click the close button. Go figure! I will edit the above code again to show what I am using and what is working at the moment.

Comment: I HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEONE IN THE FUTURE REGARDING THIS ISSUE! I cannot create answer post because apparently you cannot answer your questions within 8 hours if you are not at a certain level on these forums.